# Login as a user in Java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to do a login in Java as a user. I need to access to a protected folder.
I did it as an admin with web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Seguridad</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protegido/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/protegido/admin/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/protegido/admin/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

I need to access to a folder inside of protegido called usuarioRegistrado.

I have some doubts about doing this.

My html of login is  a bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="inicio">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="Servlet?submit=LogIn" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="centrar">Inicio de Sesión</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="j_username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="Usuario">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="j_password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contraseña</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="j_password" name="j_password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can I do this with a servlet like in the modal or I have to use j_security_check in the action.

And if in the case i have to do the second one how i can set the web.xml

Comment: It looks like you might be using spring security?

Comment: i am not using spring jsp's with mysql

Comment: I think you got the wrong idea. That xml *secures access* to `/protegido/admin/*` to users with "admin" role only -- as opposed to logs you in there

Comment: gerrytan thats not correct, see the `<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>` line

Answer (score 0):

You can find some [documentation on the FORM auth-method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbn/index.html) and [how to build the form correctly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncca/index.html) in the oracle documentation. There is no need to use Spring or whatsoever in this scenario :)

Also you have to place the `login.jsp` and `error.jsp` outside of your protected path, e.g.

```
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

to place it in the servlet mapped to "/" (the web root path).